# JavaScript: Fully rotate a string and then rotate the string in the other direction given number input

Tags: javascript, function, rotation, return, reverse

I have a function which takes a string and returns a function.  The returned function takes a number and returns a string.  The returned function returns the original string rotated by the given number.

My code below works.

```
function rotater (str){
  return function (num){

    let strArr = str.split('');
    //console.log(strArr)

    for (let i=0; i<num; i++){
      //console.log(num)

      let element = strArr[0];
      //console.log(element)

      strArr.push(element); 
      strArr.shift()
      //console.log(strArr)
    }
    return strArr.join('')
  }
}

const rotate = rotater('abcde');
rotate(4) // returns 'eabcd' as expected
```

My issue is with the next test spec.  Once a string rotates fully, it will afterwards rotate in the other direction.

Below is test spec:

```
it('once told to rotate fully will afterwards rotate in the other direction', () => {
    const rotate = rotater('helloWORLD');

    expect(rotate(1)).toEqual('elloWORLDh'); // same as before
    expect(rotate(2)).toEqual('lloWORLDhe'); // same as before

    rotate(10); // max value triggers rotation reversal

    expect(rotate(1)).toEqual('DhelloWORL');
    expect(rotate(2)).toEqual('LDhelloWOR');
    expect(rotate(6)).toEqual('oWORLDhell');

    rotate(10); // max value triggers rotation reversal

    expect(rotate(1)).toEqual('elloWORLDh');
    expect(rotate(2)).toEqual('lloWORLDhe');
    expect(rotate(6)).toEqual('ORLDhelloW');
  });
```

I'm confused by how to pass the above test spec.  Do I need to insert an if statement plus break into my code?  Please let me what code is missing to pass the above spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to set the state of the returned function. One way to do that is to include a value that you capture in a closure that indicates the direction. You can then manipulate in the function. For example:

```
function rotater (str){
  let dir = 1                  // flag captured in closure
  return function (num){
    if (num == str.length) {
        dir *= -1              // manipulate it where appropriate 
    }
```

I set the flag as positive or negative 1 because then it's really convenient to use `slice()` (which deals with negative numbers well) instead of splitting and looping with something like:

```js
function rotater (str){
  let dir = 1
  return function (num){
    if (num == str.length) {
        dir *= -1
        return str
    }
    return str.slice(dir * num) + str.slice(0, dir * num)
  }
}

const rotate = rotater('helloWORLD');
console.log(rotate(1)) 

console.log(rotate(10)) 
console.log(rotate(1)) // now reversed DhelloWORL
console.log(rotate(6))

rotate(10)
console.log(rotate(1)) // back to forward elloWORLDh
```

Comment: follow-up question: when the code hits the second instance of console.log(rotate(1)), how does it know that it needs to reverse?  Or in other words how does rotate(10) force it to reverse?

Comment: By the time dir is called the second time, the variable dir is -1. Closures are a way you can save state in your functions. Read about [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)

Comment: @PineNuts0 when you call `rotate(10)` it hits the `if (num == str.length) ` block and `dir` is changed from `1` to `-1`. This uses `dir` in the slice causing either positive or negative values in the slice.

Comment: oh wait, it sets the global dir equal to -1; so then subsequent calls are using -1;  and then when you hit rotate(10) again, you multiply -1 * -1 = 1;  and 1 is now the new global dir  ... am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Yes @PineNuts0 that's correct, except `dir` isn't global. It's local to the `rotater` function, which the returned function is able to see and manipulate because of the closure. (The returned function is able to see `str` for the same reason).

Comment: Close. The variable dir share the same scope as the anonymous function that is being returned inside rotater.